# Is $|x|^3$ differentiable or not?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

According to graph it is differentiable. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes: it is differentiable, and its derivative is $3x|x|$.

Comment: Consider a bounded function $f$ defined on an interval containing $0$. It is well known (?) that then $x^2\cdot f(x)$ is differentiable in $0$.  In our case we have $|x^3|=x^2\cdot |x|$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition

$$f(x)=|x|^3=\begin{cases}-x^3,&x<0\\{}\\\;\;\,x^3,&x\ge0\end{cases}$$

so the only *possibly* problematic problem is at $\;x=0\;$ , yet

$$\begin{align*}&\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{-x^3}x=\lim_{x\to0^-}-x^2=0\\{}\\
&\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^3}x=\lim_{x\to0^+}x^2=0\end{align*}$$

so also at $\;x=0\;$ the function's differentiable.

Comment: Hi . @donantonio . Kindly help me in this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037117/if-the-derivative-of-a-function-is-continious-then/2037130?noredirect=1#comment4181754_2037130