# If the derivative of a function is continious,then?

Tags: calculus, continuity

If the derivative of a function is continious,then which of the following must always be TRUE ?
A) The function is continious 
B) The function is differentiable 
C) The derivative of the function is differentiable
D) None

Comment: Any ideas yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If a function is

```
F(x ) =x^2/2 , x>0
      = - x^2/2 , <0
      = 6 , x=0
```

now

```
F'(x) = x ,x>0
      =-x ,x<0
      =0, x=0
```

here F'(x) is continuous . in fact it is |x| . which is continuous but not differentiable . 
But F(x) is not continuous . 
so if function is not continuous . how it can be differentiable.

so all of them is wrong option

Kindly confirm.

Comment: Use the limit definition to find the derivative at $x=0$ in your example. You'll see the limit doesn't exist. Your function isn't differentiable.

Comment: yes , My function is not continuous . But its derivative is continuous .In the question it is asked that when derivative of of F(x) is continuous . But if the derivative is continuous it does not mean that F(x) will also be continuous . So According to me all options are wrong . What you say @mrob

Comment: @AmitPal If your function isn't continuous then it can **not** be differentiable at all...In your example, the function isn't differentiable at $\;x=0\;$ and thus it is not a counterexample.

Comment: Yes I agree that if function is not continuous then it will not be differentiable at all . My question is this if derivative is continuous it does not mean that function will be continuous . Am i right here ? that is why i wrote this example

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry . I got my silly mistake . thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

(A) Is true as differentiability implies continuity

(B) This is trivially true...

(C) This one isn't necessarily true, as for example:

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}-\cfrac{x^2}2,&x<0\\{}\\\;\;\,\cfrac{x^2}2,&x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

This function is every where differentiable and its derivative is

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}-x,&x<0\\{}\\\;\;\,x,&x\ge0\end{cases}\;\;=|x|$$

But this function is **not** differentiable at $\;x=0\;$ , though it is continous everywhere